# Strange sound in speakers when the refridgerator goes standby

Tags: power, sound, speakers, ups

I live in a room which has two power sockets and the following devices, as illustrated in this diagram: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Byu0T6y2SLeENDdvNGVCWHFBWmc/edit

All devices look exactly as they are presented on the diagram.

**1. First power socket:**
I have plugged a coupler with a surge protection which then has my refrigerator plugged in to it.

**2. Second power socket.**
This power socket is in the same room. It has a UPS plugged in to it, then another coupler is being plugged in to the UPS. I have three devices: Laptop, Router and a 5.1 Audio system plugged in to the coupler.

**The problem:**
Whenever the refrigerator is being turned off (it works for a while, freezing the food then it shut downs to standby mode) a crackling-like sound is heard in the speakers  of the Audio 5.1 system (if they are powered) which is really annoying.

I cannot understand what could be causing the problem. The fridge and the 5.1 audio are on different power sockets. I thought when I buy an UPS the sound would be gone but it's still no difference.

**The question:**
Could anyone please explain me why this sound is being heard every time the fridge turns off? 
Does it damage my speakers? 
How I could solve this problem? 
Should I buy a separate voltage stabilizator or whatever to fix it?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Does it still happen if the fridge is plugged directly into the wall?

Comment: Yeah Spehro, that was my guess, get rid of the frig surge suppressor, they may not be so good at high currents.

Comment: It does happen both ways.

Comment: Would adding a choke on the refrigerator's power cord help? Wrapping the audio cables with aluminium foil could help but it would be ugly...

Comment: OK Does it get louder/ stronger when the Audio is moved close to the frig?  (Maybe it's hard to move the audio system.) If it's airborne EMI then one might expect more... if it is interference through the AC line then it shouldn't change much with distance.  The weird part of this question is why it interferes when the fridge shuts off.

Comment: Just to add a note, this had happened to me while I was living in a different house, with a different stereo system too.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it is an unintentional airborne EM transmission of noise caused when the 'fridge motor stops turning when the fridge has reached the lowest temperature it is set to. It takes two things to get this interference and the first is the generation and the 2nd is the lack of EM interference protection in your amplifier's inputs.

It's unlikely to damage anything and I guess only lasts a fraction of a second. If it lasts longer please do say. I'll also suggest if you listen hard enough you might hear a little bit of interference when the motor kicks back in.

It might be difficult to solve without stripping down the amplifier but you could diagnose this further by removing wiring going to inputs on the amplifier - minimize wires just to see if the problem disappears or improves - then at least you'll understand the mechanism a bit better and might be able to put some suppression components on the worst input.

Comment: The speakers claim to be magnetically shielded. They are not that cheap, quite the opposite. Also I have the same problem when using professional studio monitor speakers in this room too (each speaker costing one thousand dollars). Are you sure it's all from the airborne EM transmissions because I am not as convinced. Thank you for you detailed answer.

Comment: Pickup like this is usually a wiring or interconnect issue. Mag shielded speakers are irrelevant to this problem. It's likely an electric field interference gettingto where the signal is smallest at amplifier inputs.

Comment: @Hellen, does it happen only when the refrigerator is switching on and off or does it persist when the device is off?

Comment: @sherrellbc: It happens only when the fridge turns off. Issue is not present when the fridge activates. OK, my 5.1 system which claims to be magnetically shielded might not be shielded the best way but the new monitors for my friend which are professional studio equipment are. Could the problem lay in the electricity circuits from the entire building?

Comment: @Hellen - if you want to prove/disprove the electricity supply in the building, move the speakers (and associated wiring) further away (like to another room) and see if the same thing still happens. My guess is that it is a proximity thing and it's solved by suppressing either the source (fridge) or the inputs.

Comment: It still happens. How I am supposed to suppress either the source or the inputs? I know nothing of electricity apparently. :)